# Duplicate codeigniter installation to a different subdirectory on same server

Tags: installation, duplicates

I am trying to create a sandbox version of a codeigniter installation on the same server, only in a different subdirectory. So I have a development version

www.example.com/development

And I want

www.example.com/sandbox

I did

```
$ cd www
$ mkdir sandbox
$ cp -R development/* sandbox
```

I changed sandbox/application/config/config.php, so that it has

```
$config[‘base_url’]    = ‘http://www.example.com/sandbox/’;
```

I also made a sandbox version of the database the application uses, and changed application/config/database.php accordingly.

But in the sandbox version, when I click on any menu item, like “Log In”, I get a “Coming Soon Page” instead of the Log In form. The menus work on the development version.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I had done

```
cp -R www/development/* www/sandbox
```

But this fails to copy development/.htacess, which has the rewrite rules needed by codeignitor.